# Oracle Reports SELECT INTO Not Selecting

Tags: oracle, triggers, oraclereports

I'm working on a Report in Oracle Reports Builder, and having issues with my AFTERPFORM trigger. When viewing the report, it seems like the year is being processed properly, while the period and subperiod are using their initial values. I'm confused because they are the exact same select statement, but are not working as intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function AfterPForm return boolean is
  v_subpdenddt_user date;
  v_subpdenddt_max date;
  v_rowcount integer;
begin

select value into year from wos_report_param where parameter = 'year' and sequence_num = :sequencenum;
select value into period from wos_report_param where parameter = 'period' and sequence_num = :sequencenum;
select value into user_subpd from wos_report_param where parameter = 'subpd' and sequence_num = :sequencenum;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check variable datatypes are they matched the database columns?

try to change the above code to work with varchar2 variables, then convert varchar2 to date if you want to deal with dates, or to numbers if you want to deal with numbers.